# Return filenames from jquery object with serializearray

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am having some troubles getting filenames from a jquery script.

I have multiple hidden fields containing filenames from a fileinput in my form and I use this to get filenames:

```
var fn = $('input[name="filename[]"]').serializeArray();
var post_var = {'filename':fn};
```

and then:

```
return JSON.stringify({
  "filename": post_var
});
```

That gives me something like this:

```
[Object { name="filename[]", value="703640495-qr-flo.png"}, Object { name="filename[]", value="703640495-qr-pgl.png"}]
```

But I am not sure how I should get the content in "value" with my current php script that is like this:

```
 foreach($filename as $key => $value) {
    $imgrow = $this->db->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO '. $this->config->db_prefix .'_images (aid, image) VALUES (:aid, :image)');
    $imgrow->bindValue(':aid', $id);
    $imgrow->bindParam(':image', strtolower($value));
    $imgrow->execute();
```

}

if I var_dump($filename) I get this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#104 (1) {
    ["filename"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#105 (2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(10) "filename[]"
        ["value"]=>
        string(20) "703640495-qr-flo.png"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#106 (2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(10) "filename[]"
        ["value"]=>
        string(20) "703640495-qr-pgl.png"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
foreach(array_shift($filename) as $file ) {
   foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
      $imgrow = $this->db->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO '. $this->config->db_prefix .'_images (aid, image) VALUES (:aid, :image)');
         $imgrow->bindValue(':aid', $id);
         $imgrow->bindParam(':image', strtolower($value->value));
         $imgrow->execute();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are located at `$filename[0]['filename']` so you can:

1. Array shift the `$filename` variable which returns the array located at `$filename[0]['filename']`.
2. Then loop through the returned array, where each loop iteration will provide you an array containing the name abnd value keys.

Like so:

```
foreach( array_shift($filename) as $file ) {

   $file['name']; // the file name (always filename[] so ignore it)
   $file['value']; //the file value (the real filename)

}
```

Comment: Sweet! Works smoothly with my addition as edited in my question! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
foreach($filename["filename"] as $key=>$value){

    $thisFilename=$filename["filename"][$key]["value"];

}
```